# Using に in place of が

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> ボクラなんて、印象**に**残らないだろうね、
>   People like us probably don't make an impression.

I belive 残る is intransitive so I suppose the literal translation is more like "For people like us an impression is probably not left".

I don't understand why the particle に is used here. Why is it not が? How would the sentence change if I replaced に with が?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel this 印象 is used as the "place" where ボクラ remains. It's used in the same way as the following:

> - 東京にしばらく残る to stay in Tokyo for a while
> - 記憶に残る演説 the speech that remains in my memory
> - 耳に残る to linger in one's ears

You can also say:

> - その話はあまり印象にない。 （≒印象に残っていない）
> - 今まで読んだ中で一番印象にある小説は○○だ。

So one can say this 印象 is semantically interchangeable with 記憶, but it may be best to just memorize this as an idiom because it's very common. ボクラなんて印象が残らないだろうね also perfectly makes sense, but I feel it's less common.